# GitHub heading text to URL fragment identifier

Tags: github, url, markdown

In GitHub's markdown we can create an anchor to any heading, like the example below:

```
# Heading 1
Click [here](#heading-2) to go to the second heading

# Heading 2
This is the second heading :)
```

The problem is that I couldn't find the rules to convert the text in the heading (in this case "Heading 2") to the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) (in this case `heading-2`). There are some non-intuitive behaviors, like some characters getting omitted and accented letters not changing to their non-accented versions ("Á!á?É!é?" would be turned into `ááéé`, for example).

I want to automate this process so it would be really useful to see the rules for this conversion with all possible cases and exceptions.

Where can I find this information?